# Merging typed structs with FP-TS

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

When using FP-TS I often end up with *structs* being inside a `Task` or an `IO`. I managed to solve the problem by writing a merge function and separate lift functions that make it work with `Task` or `IO`. See the included code example for a more detailed explanation. The code works but I'm wondering if the custom functions I wrote are already available in FP-TS in some shape or form.

```js
import { deepStrictEqual as assertEqual } from 'assert'
import { IO, of, io, map } from 'fp-ts/lib/IO';
import { sequenceT } from 'fp-ts/lib/Apply';
import { pipe, tupled } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';

type Merge<A, B> = A & B
function merge<A, B>(a: A, b: B): Merge<A, B> {
  return {...a, ...b}
}

type Foo = { foo: 123 }
type Bar = { bar: 456 }
type FooBar = Merge<Foo, Bar>;

const foo: Foo = { foo: 123 }
const bar: Bar = { bar: 456 }
const fooBar: FooBar = merge(foo, bar)

type IOLift<A, AS extends Array<any>, B> = (a: IO<A>, ...as: { [I in keyof AS]: IO<AS[I]> }) => IO<B> 
function ioLift<A, AS extends Array<any>, B>(f: (a: A, ...as: AS) => B): IOLift<A, AS, B> {
  return (...a) => pipe(
    sequenceT(io)(...a),
    map(tupled(f))
  )
}

const ioMerge = ioLift(merge)

const ioFoo: IO<Foo> = of(foo)
const ioBar: IO<Bar> = of(bar)
const ioFooBar: IO<FooBar> = ioMerge(ioFoo, ioBar)

assertEqual(ioFooBar(), fooBar)
```

Answer (score 3):

Merging structs of the same type can be achieved with a `Monoid` instance (see `getStructMonoid`), but you're looking to merge structs with different interfaces, and there's not a type class for that operation. However, `Object.assign` is equivalent to your `merge` function, except that it can merge up to four arguments (any more than that and you'll get an `any` in TypeScript).

As for `ioLift`, there's nothing equivalent to that in `fp-ts`, but your implementation of `sequenceT` + `map` is the standard way of applying a function to some arguments when they each happen to be wrapped in some applicative functor, standard for `fp-ts`, that is, given the limitations of TypeScript (see @gcanti's comment [here](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/issues/910#issuecomment-511350062) about why there's not `liftN` function).

Given how trivial the `sequenceT` + `map` composition is, one could argue that it doesn't meet the [Fairbairn Threshold](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2012-February/017548.html), meaning it's easier to just combine `sequenceT` + `map` inline whenever you find yourself in this situation rather than writing a specialized utility `liftWhatever` for every applicative functor you come across.